# .NET Framework - Environment Variables return null

Tags: c#, docker, environment-variables, windows-container, .net-4.7.2

I would like to get environment variables from windows container which is ran by docker command but I could not get expected value of the variables.

In Dockerfile, I placed one of instructions likes

```
ENV Hello=World
```

In command prompt of windows, it runs a command of

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

and the image build successfully. Then run the image

```
docker run -e "Hello=Bye" myapp
```

In C#, I tried to get the environment variable **Hello** by

```
string debug = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Hello");
```

and the `debug` would get `World`.
If the instruction `ENV Hello=World` is not placed in Dockerfile, the `debug` would get `null`.
I don't know what I should do in C# that getting `debug` with the value `Bye` which is my expected result. Thanks for the help.

Comment: just my guess, but can you try `docker run -e Hello=Bye` ?

Comment: Same result if the command without quotation marks on setting ```-e```. Is it different when removing quotation marks?